# Windows Command Line: Display fully qualified paths of and count files in a directory and its subdirectories that have a user-defined extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm writing a batch file that does the following:
takes an argument (%1) that is a directory path. Then, it asks the user to enter an extension (%ext%). Finally, the batch file uses a for loop to count up how many files exist in the directory and its subdirectories that end with the user provided extension. Also, as the loop does this, it also outputs to console lines of fully qualified paths for each file.

What I'm struggling with is the for loop. This was the first version of it:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s/b "%1" ^| findstr /e "!ext!"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set line=%%f
    echo !line!
)
```

This code does work if I enter any extension with a period at the beginning (ex: .exe). It counts up the lines (I display the count value later) and the for loop also displays a fully qualified path to each .exe file in every subdirectory.

However, the problem is if I would enter extension exe (.exe with no dot) it would then also count up any folders and filenames that exist that end with "exe". I don't want it to do that. I only want it to count the number of files with .exe extensions whether I enter "exe" or ".exe".

I tried again with Command Processor Extensions:

```
for %%F in ('dir /b "%1\*.!ext!"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set line=%%~dpxfF
    echo !line!
)
```

But I clearly don't know what I'm doing here. I think that somehow I should be able to use %~xF, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how it's used after googling for hours. I found similar questions, but I couldn't figure it out.

Could someone write me the for loop that would accomplish what I need it to, and explain how it works? It could be great if it would be as close to my original loops as it can.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Two options. Read the help for the DIR command so you can see the option to suppress directories or look at using a FOR /R command.

Comment: `set /p Ext=Enter Extension` and `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s/b "%1\*.%ext%") do (`

Comment: The proper syntax of a plain `for` is: `for %%F in ("%1\*.!ext!") do (`

Answer (score 1):

Squashman, thank you so much. I looked into suppressing directories with dir but I didn't bother to try to do dir /a-d like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s/b /a-d "%1" ^| findstr /e "!ext!"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set line=%%f
    echo !line!
)
```

This code works, but now I'm confused as to why it works. Because I'm only suppressing directories, the names of the files (and their extensions) still appear. But if a file is named "exe.txt" is in the directory, and I count up the all files with "exe" extensions, it does not count the exe.txt file as one of them.

Why does it not do that? It does it with folders. I'm guessing is because a file name and its extension type is a single value? CMD does not separate those things, and so an extension will always be glued to the file name?

I am also curious to see if someone could do it with Command Processor Extensions because I know it's possible. I'll keep trying, but Squashman's solution is great!

Comment: As per the output of `findstr /?`, the `/e` flag of `findstr` matches a pattern at the end of the line. exe.txt is not picked up because "exe" is not at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to compare the end of the string to the extension. This will find files that end with whatever is in the EXT variable. I appropriated the strlen function from SS64.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "DIR=%~1"
SET "EXT=ps1"
CALL:strlen %EXT%

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /S /B /A:-D "%DIR%"`) DO (
    SET "FN=%%~f"
    IF /I "!FN:~-%_strlen%!" EQU "%EXT%" (ECHO "%%~f")
)

EXIT /B 0

REM ========================================

:strlen
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Remove any quotes
Set "_str=%~1"

:: Test if empty
IF NOT DEFINED _str ECHO String Length = 0 & ENDLOCAL & SET "_strlen=0" & GOTO:EOF

FOR /L %%g IN (0,1,64) DO (
    REM extract one character
    SET "_char=!_str:~%%g,1!"
    REM if _char is empty we are at the end of the string
    IF "!_char!" EQU "" (
        Echo String Length = %%g
        ENDLOCAL & set "_strlen=%%g"
        GOTO:EOF
    )
)
```

Using PowerShell, you could just:

```
$dir = '.'
$ext = 'ps1'
if ($ext[0] -ne '.') { $ext = '.' + $ext }

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $dir -Filter "*$ext" | Select-Object -expand FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

For the user provided extension, I would just check if the first character is a **`.`** and add it if necessary. Also, because it works only with files, I would use the `Where` command.

```bat
If Not "%ext:~,1%"=="." Set "ext=.%ext%"
Set "count=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%F In ('Where/R "%~1" *%ext% 2^>Nul') Do (Set/A count+=1
    Echo %%F)
Echo Total files with extension %ext% is %count%
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I will be adding the "." to prevent it from locating the extension "exe" if I search for "xe".